# How can i exit from a while loop? Based on my pre-defined count down in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a loop which need to be turned off so that it can continue to next statements with some values else it crash. What is the best way to do so? For example:

```
if (data.startsWith("tcp") ) 
{
   /* main.strings should have a value but it may take a while */
   main.start("i generate some encoding/decoding, i take uncertain time...");

   int i = 0;
   while(main.strings != null) 
   {
     /* Maximum 20 time waiting is accepted, else not */
     if (i > 20 ) break; 
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     i++;
   }

   /* It crash, if main.start() is not creating the main.strings  
    * so there is a uncertain specific time, for this but we however can't wait long
    */
   main.NowUDPSend(main.strings); 
   ...
}
```

Is this the best way to handle the realtime while loop, so that i can exit exactly after 20 times limit over to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; main.strings != null && i <= 20; ++i) {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

will do it, but I would really look into using [`main.wait(20000)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) and have the thing that sets `main.strings` do [`main.notifyAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) afterwards.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html for a good tutorial.

> Threads often have to coordinate their actions. The most common coordination idiom is the guarded block. Such a block begins by polling a condition that must be true before the block can proceed. There are a number of steps to follow in order to do this correctly.
>
> Suppose, for example `guardedJoy` is a method that must not proceed until a shared variable joy has been set by another thread. Such a method could, in theory, simply loop until the condition is satisfied, but that loop is wasteful, since it executes continuously while waiting.
>
> ```
> public void guardedJoy() {
>   //Simple loop guard. Wastes processor time. Don't do this!
>   while(!joy) {}
>   System.out.println("Joy has been achieved!");
> }
> ```
>
> A more efficient guard invokes `Object.wait` to suspend the current thread. The invocation of `wait` does not return until another thread has issued a notification that some special event may have occurred — though not necessarily the event this thread is waiting for:
>
> ```
> public synchronized guardedJoy() {
>     //This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
>     //be the event we're waiting for.
>     while(!joy) {
>         try {
>             wait();
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
>     }
>     System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> When `wait` is invoked, the thread releases the lock and suspends execution. At some future time, another thread will acquire the same lock and invoke `Object.notifyAll`, informing all threads waiting on that lock that something important has happened:
>
> ```
> public synchronized notifyJoy() {
>     joy = true;
>     notifyAll();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

While the wait/notifyAll will work, there are a number of implementations of locks and barriers in the JDK under the java.util.concurrent package that are much easier to use and use correctly than the basic primitives of concurrency like wait.

For this, check out CountdownLatch.  It does exactly what you want.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Russel, while you're right about there being lots of cool stuff in `.concurrent`, I think the OP wants to wait a maximum of 20 seconds for an action to be performed once.   I don't think he wants the other thread to perform an action 20 times.